# `sort_by': comparison of Array with Array failed (no nil data)

Tags: ruby

```
class CustomSorter
  attr_accessor :start_date, :available

  def initialize(start_date, available)
    @start_date = Time.mktime(*start_date.split('-'))
    @available = available
  end

end

cs1 = CustomSorter.new('2015-08-01', 2)
cs2 = CustomSorter.new('2015-08-02', 1)
cs3 = CustomSorter.new('2016-01-01', 1)
cs4 = CustomSorter.new('2015-02-01', 3)
cs5 = CustomSorter.new('2015-03-01', 4)

sorted = [cs1, cs2, cs3, cs4, cs5].sort_by { |cs| [Time.now <= cs.start_date, (cs.available || 0)] }

puts sorted.map(&:start_date)
```

But it fails:

> custom_sorter.rb:17:in `sort_by': comparison of Array with Array failed (ArgumentError)

I know that nil might produce this error. But there is no nil in my data.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have pasted above code in console and executed with no errors. Please help me to reproduce this issue. because i am getting this issue on production, but not on local server.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When the sorting algorithm compares the created arrays `[Time.now <= cs.start_date, (cs.available || 0)]`, it compares them element-wise.

The initial elements are booleans. There is no order defined for booleans.

```
irb(main):001:0> true <=> false
=> nil
```

You can get around this by creating integer values, e.g.

```
[cs1, cs2, cs3, cs4, cs5].sort_by { |cs| [Time.now <= cs.start_date ? 0 : 1, (cs.available || 0)] }
```

Comment: Just adding this, because maybe someone has the same problem as me: "Time.now <= cs.start_date" would obviously end in an boolean ("true" or "false"). And if I understood correctly ("it compares them element-wise"), it would compare cs1 Time.now <= start_date (=boolean) with cs2 Time.now <= start_date (=boolean). Which then fails (because boolean <=> boolean end up in nil). Am I right? I had this issue with comparing/sorting version information and fixed it with (example): `@software.versions.sort_by{ |sv| [(sv.major.to_i || 0), (sv.minor.to_i || 0), (sv.patch.to_i || 0)] }.last`

Comment: @JensSchmidt: Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Just noting as this caught me out for a couple of minutes. If your hash has both string and symbols as keys, this same error will occur and it's not entirely obvious.